# Wrapping non-child elements in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I currently have a html document in the following format:

```
<h1>a</h1>
<p>bla</p>
<p>more bla</p>

<h1>b</h1>
<p>different bla</p>
```

I am looking for a way to wrap both the `<h1>` and it's following `<p>` inside a div, so it would look like:

```
<div>
    <h1>a</h1>
    <p>bla</p>
    <p>more bla</p>
</div>

<div>
    <h1>b</h1>
    <p>different bla</p>
</div>
```

But I have been unsuccessful using wrap and wrapAll to achieve this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var tagName = 'h1';
$(tagName).each(function ()
{
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.add($this.nextUntil(tagName)).wrapAll('<div></div>');
});
```

[Demo demo demo demo demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/JpsXh/)

Answer (score 1):

What you could do would be to create a `<div>` where you want it in the DOM, and then move the elements you want to be inside it into it.

For example (probably could be better):

```
$("h1").before("<div></div>");
$("h1").each(function() {
    $(this)
        .nextUntil("h1").andSelf()
        .appendTo(
            $(this).prev("div")
        );
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can add a few more css classes it might be easier.
See http://jsfiddle.net/avaXp/

```
<h1 class='one'>a</h1>
<p class='one'>bla</p>
<p class='one'>more bla</p>

<h1 class='two'>b</h1>
<p class='two'>different bla</p>



$('.one').wrapAll("<div></div>")
$('.two').wrapAll("<div></div>")
```